# What's the best way to do a FormsAuthentication.SignOut() in MVC from within an action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

I have a SignOut action inside a LoginController like so:

```
[Authorize]
        public ActionResult SignOut()
        {
            var membershipProvider = new MembershipProviderFactory().Create();
            membershipProvider.SignOut();

            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

It's all working fine but I am concerned about the two round-trips back and forth between the client and the server that this method will cause.

**First round-trip:**
The `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()` calls `GetDefaultLoginPage()` (the one that's declared in the `<forms>` authentication element in the web.config file and does a response.redirect to that. That's already one 301/302 round-trip.

**Second round-trip:**
return `RedirectToAction("Index")` causes another one.

Ideally, the `RedirectToAction("Index")` call must be redundant because it is also redirecting the user to the default `HttpGet` action on the `Login` controller which will call the default Login screen view, which is the same as the default login page.

But if I exclude that `RedirectToAction` call from the `SignOut` action, I must return some `ActionResult` type. What should I return?